# Hadoop Data node is not getting started

Tags: hadoop

I am using Hadoop version 1.2.1. on single node. When I try to start all nodes using bin/start-all.sh on linux. Data node does not start. In the log file of data node:
"

```
2014-02-19 12:27:41,085 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = HH-Xeon-2/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_25
************************************************************/
2014-02-19 12:27:41,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2014-02-19 12:27:41,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2014-02-19 12:27:41,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2014-02-19 12:27:41,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2014-02-19 12:27:41,519 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2014-02-19 12:27:41,524 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2014-02-19 12:27:46,472 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot access storage directory /app/hadoop/tmp2
2014-02-19 12:27:46,477 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /app/hadoop/tmp2 does not exist
2014-02-19 12:27:46,582 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: All specified directories are not accessible or do not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1812)

2014-02-19 12:27:46,583 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
"
```

Directory does exist and it has the permission of chmod 755. With 777 or 775 data node log file give me error that permission previlige is not correct.
Can anyone please help me out with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing "ls /app/hadoop/tmp2" as the user that DataNode is running as?

Comment: thanks for replying ... I have solved the problem. I have changed the ownership of tmp2 directory.